# Can you send push notifications to an Ionic hybrid app using Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, mobilepush, push, ionic

Does anyone know if it is possible to send mobile push notifications from Marketing Cloud 'MobilePush' to a hybrid mobile app (built using the Ionic framework)?

All the developer documentation I have found within Marketing Cloud is for Android and IOS 'native' applications. I am looking instead for a JavaScript solution.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Many customers have successfully implemented the MarketingCloudSdk with their framework-based applications though it is not officially supported.

UPDATED 20230530 with 'hints' to get this to work:

## Ionic SFMC Cordova Plugin integration

## tldr;

Ionic works with SFMC Cordova plugin without any changes to our artifact, but we need to update our documentation to help Ionic customers know what the pain points are and how to resolve them.

## Findings

1. We can install market Cordova plugin within a ionic App (mainly capacitor based).
2. ionic capacitor require changes `capacitor.config.ts` and most of our SDK config is in `config.xml` for Cordova.
3. Our category `AppDelegate+MCCordovaPlugin` is not working in ionic.

## **Resolution**

1. The customer needs to edit `capacitor.config.ts` of their ionic project with the SFMC config settings in this file.
2. The customer needs to implement the AppDelegate delegate methods.

> Note: I have verified with a simple push and its working fine with ionic app and with our Cordova plugin.

---

## Required Changes for Ionic to Work

### 1. Add plugin to your application via [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-marketingcloudsdk)

```
`// Changed for capacitor`
`npm i cordova``-``plugin``-``marketingcloudsdk
``ionic build 
ionic capacitor copy ios`
```

> **Required for iOS**

> You must have [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) installed for the iOS platform integration. Execute the following commands from terminal to install:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod repo update
```

### 2. Modify your application's  `capacitor.config.ts`  to configure the plugin

```
const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'io.ionic.starter', //Your app id
  appName: 'ionicapp',  //Your app name
  webDir: 'build',
  bundledWebRuntime: false,
  cordova: {
    preferences: { //Salesforce Marketing Cloud Config
      "com.salesforce.marketingcloud.app_id":"{Marketing Cloud application id}",
      "com.salesforce.marketingcloud.access_token":"{Marketing Cloud access token}",
      "com.salesforce.marketingcloud.tenant_specific_endpoint":"{URL retrieved from Marketing Cloud adminstration page}",
      "com.salesforce.marketingcloud.analytics": "{true|false}",
      "com.salesforce.marketingcloud.delay_registration_until_contact_key_is_set": "{true|false}"        
    },
  }
};
```

### 3. Enable iOS Push

Add the following code in App Delegate

```
import UserNotifications
import MarketingCloudSDK

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Other customer code as needed

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    return true
  }
    
  // MobilePush SDK: REQUIRED IMPLEMENTATION
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_setDeviceToken(deviceToken)
  }
        
  // MobilePush SDK: REQUIRED IMPLEMENTATION
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
  }
    
  // MobilePush SDK: REQUIRED IMPLEMENTATION
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_setNotificationUserInfo(userInfo)
    completionHandler(.newData)
  }
    
  // MobilePush SDK: REQUIRED IMPLEMENTATION
  @available(iOS 10.0, *)
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_setNotificationRequest(response.notification.request)
    completionHandler()
  }

  // MobilePush SDK: REQUIRED IMPLEMENTATION
  @available(iOS 10.0, *)
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.alert)
  }
}
```

Edit:
updated the configuration to fix an issue with `delay_registration_until_contact_key_is_set`

Comment: I appreciate your swift reply. Do you know of any code examples? Without documentation or guidance, it's very hard to achieve.

Comment: I have no access to customer implementations.  I would open a ticket with your Salesforce Account Representative.  They can put you in touch with a solutions/success engineer.

Comment: @PhilAllen have you solved this issue before? appreciate if you can send documentation on how to connect mobile push to Ionic app platform. thanks!